# Why does changing CSS width behave weird when using short intervals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The idea is to have a progress bar which loads in 20 seconds from 0% to 100% and then starts over from 0. To accomplish that I use `setInterval` in combination with `jQuery.css('width', '+=0.1%)`.

One interval counts to 20 seconds, the other one adds 0.1% to the width of a div every 20 milliseconds. Should reach 100% when the first timer is up, right?

But it doesn't. First the width isn't added as intended: it's not beeing counted in 0.1% steps but way more places behind the comma. Second the 20 seconds are over long before reaching 100%. Different browsers give different results here. Chrome comes pretty close to 100% before starting over, Firefox 20 seconds were over when reaching 70% in my site...

Even when using 1% steps instead of 0.1% steps it still doesn't properly add up, I still get places behind the comma although there shouldn't be any.

Example code:

```js
var interval;
$('.progressbar').css('width', '0%');
interval= setInterval(function() {
  $('.progressbar').css('width', '+=0.1%');
}, 20);

setInterval(startLoading, 20000);

function startLoading() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  $('.progressbar').css('width', '0%');
  interval= setInterval(function() {
    $('.progressbar').css('width', '+=0.1%');
  }, 20);
}
```

```css
.progressbar{
    height: 10px;
    background: #0060ff;
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar"></div>
```

Comment: Timers are not super-accurate. You'd probably be better off keeping track of *actual* elapsed time and set the width to an explicit percentage based on that.

Comment: @Pointy How exactly would I do that? The idea was to get a simple smooth progress bar. What irritates me the most is that Firefox and Chrome are not able to count up in 0.1% steps - while Edge an Internet Explorer suprisingly are able to.

Comment: _“it's not beeing counted in 0.1% steps but way more places behind the comma”_ - probably due to the inherent inaccuracy of floats. _“a progress bar which loads in 20 seconds from 0% to 100% and then starts over from 0”_ - why not use a CSS animation of the width for that to begin with? That would probably go a lot smoother, than fiddling with JS timers. (If you need to start or stop this at a certain point via script, then add/remove a class that triggers the animation to the element.)

Comment: @misorude Good point. Most likely the solution to go with. Still I'm interested in why the behaviour is so weird here.

Comment: What I meant was that you'd note the time at the start of the process, and then in the 20ms timer you'd check the actual time again, note the difference, and compute the actual percentage of the way to 20 seconds, and set the percentage width from that.

Comment: Because spawning new async function every 20ms takes time which is not fixed (based on current CPU/memory resources). JS does not work in parallel so one spawn can delay few ms and other not..it's controlled by internal scheduler's priority. When you spawn it every 1sec..you dont recognize few ms delay while every 20ms, it can be noticable difference..

Comment: Why are you not using CSS Transitions? will fix the issue for the most part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css animation or jquery `.animate()`.

You just have to set the **duration** to `20000` and everything will work fine. If you have to stop it at some point just add a condition around the `progressBarLoop` function in the animate callback. (I set the duration to 5000 so we don't have to wait 20 second to have the restart)

```js
var stop = false;

function progressBarLoop() {
  $('.progressbar').css('width', '0%');
  $('.progressbar').animate({
    width:'100%'
  }, 5000, 'linear', function() {
    if(!stop) {
      progressBarLoop();
    }
  });
  
}

 progressBarLoop();
```

```css
.progressbar{
    height: 10px;
    background: #0060ff;
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar"></div>
```

Comment: It's hard to chose the most helpful answer here. I went with CSS animation + starting it over via removing/adding the class - which is trickier than it sounds: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/
I chose this answer cause it adds the jQuery animate possibility, which wasn't discussed in the comments already.

Answer (score 2):

1. Keep track of elapsed time instead of setting a timer for more accuracy.
2. Use CSS3 Animation to reduce the timer differences between browser.

This [link](https://www.atyantik.com/animating-the-progress-bar-cross-browser-html5-css3/) might be useful

Answer (score 2):

Why is it behaving weirdly? Because timers are not accurate and you are adding 0.1% to the existing width, not 0.1 to the percentage (0.1 + 0.1% = 0.1001%, etc).

Your code should look something more like this...

```js
$('.progressbar').css('width', '0%');

setTimeout(function startLoading() {
  var width = $('.progressbar').prop('style').width;
  var newWidth = parseFloat(width) + 0.1;

  if (newWidth < 100) {
    $('.progressbar').css('width', newWidth + '%');
  } else {
    $('.progressbar').css('width', '0%');
  }

  setTimeout(startLoading, 20);
}, 20);
```

```css
.progressbar{
    height: 10px;
    background: #0060ff;
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar"></div>
```

Comment: While this approach adds the % correctly in chrome, I'm pretty sure my original coding does not add 0.1% of the current width to it, since this would result in the bar not moving at all (it starts at 0). I think it has more to do with how Chrome/Firefox handle float values.

Comment: It appears you are correct about the percentage. It must be something jQuery is doing than, as my native JavaScript math code above does not exhibit the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why you use 2 timers to know when the loading is done.
Just check when the progress reaches 100 and call the callback.

```js
function LoadingBar() {
    var self = this; // id use ES classes instead but you seem to prefer the old school way.
    this.element = $('.progressbar');
    this.progress = 0;
    this.stepSize = 0.1;
    this.progressInterval;
    this.start = function() {
         console.log('loading');
         self.progress = 0;
         if (self.progressInterval) {
             clearInterval(self.progressInterval);
         }
         
         self.progressInterval = setInterval(self.updateProgress, 10);
    }
    
    this.updateProgress = function() {
      self.progress += self.stepSize;
      // round off
      self.progress = Math.round(self.progress * 10) / 10;
      self.element.css('width', self.progress + '%');
      if (self.progress >= 100) {
        clearInterval(self.progressInterval);
        self.onComplete();
      }
    }
    this.onComplete = function() {
        console.log('completed');
        //start over
        self.start();
    }
}
var loadingBar = new LoadingBar();
loadingBar.start();
```

```css
.progressbar{
  height: 10px;
  background: #0060ff;
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="progressbar"></div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/xpvt214o/858622/

Answer (score 1):

Timers are not super accurate. From experience intervals lower than 50 ms can trigger up to 100% less frequently than expected (i.e. every 100ms) depending on many many factors. If you want the progress to fill in 20 seconds then calculating the real percentage on each tick would make it appear more accurate.

```js
var defaultDuration=20000; //Change this to whatever

function loadingBar(duration) {
    var interval;
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var endTime = startTime + duration;

    $('.progressbar').css('width', '0%');
    interval= setInterval(function() { 
      var pc = (new Date().getTime() - startTime)/(endTime-startTime);
      $('.progressbar').css('width', (pc * 100) +'%');
    }, 20);
    return interval;
}
var int = loadingBar(defaultDuration); 
setInterval(function () { 
     clearInterval(int); 
     int = loadingBar(defaultDuration); 
}, defaultDuration);
```

```css
.progressbar{
    height: 10px;
    background: #0060ff;
    border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progressbar"></div>
```